# How to update Pdf_view in tkinter?

Tags: pdf, tkinter

My code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdf

def donothing():
   x = 0
def open():
    file=askopenfile()
    v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
    v2 = v1.pdf_view(root,
                    pdf_location = file,
                    width = 200, height = 100)
    v2.pack()
root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=open)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=donothing)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=donothing)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

If you open first pdf file it's word very good.But
when you open a other pdf file then it's not update.So how can I fix it?Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First every time you call `pdf_view(...)`, a new instance of tkinter `Frame` is created and `pack()`, so the second instance of `Frame` is packed below the first one.  But since the first `Frame` is a bit long, the second one is out of the viewable area and so you cannot see it.  You can see the second one by using a smaller *height*, for example, change from 100 to 50, then you can see both the frames.

To fix the issue, you need to destroy the first instance of the `Frame`.  Also `tkPDFViewer` uses a class variable `img_object_li` (a `list`) to stores all the images (extracted from the PDF file), so you need to clear it before opening another PDF file:

```py
v2 = None  # change v2 to global variable

def open():
    global v2
    file = askopenfile()
    if file:
        # if old instance exists, destroy it first
        if v2:
            v2.destroy()
        v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
        # clear the stored image list
        v1.img_object_li.clear()
        # shows the new images extracted from PDF file
        v2 = v1.pdf_view(root, pdf_location=file, width=200, height=50) # smaller height
        v2.pack()
```

Comment: VERY useful, since that's FAR from intuitive.  Do you know where I can find any documentation about tkPDFViewer ? I found only a trivial example.

Comment: @JackGriffin You can simply look into its code, it is not hard to understand.